# redirecting a rewrite rule to another rewrite rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My website was made up in the following way:

```
/vacation/country/
RewriteRule ^vacation/(.*)/ vacation.php?country=$1 [L]
```

which was redirected to a certain file on the server. 
I now want to change/update this to

```
/vacation-country/
```

I use a redirect for this

```
RewriteRule ^vacation/(.*)/ vacation-$1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^vacation-(.*)/ vacation.php?country=$1 [L]
```

This is unfortunality giving a 404 error, including the full path of the server. I tried to remove the [L] from the rewrite rules, but without any success.

Any idea's how I should setup the redirects in the correct way to archive the above?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$` in your regex:

```
RewriteRule ^vacation/([^/]+)/?$ /vacation-$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^vacation-([^/]+)/?$ /vacation.php?country=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I tried your suggested solution, but still the same effect, getting a 404 error message. Any way to figure out what is causing the problem?

Comment: Which URI is causing 404 is it `/vacation-country/`? Also make sure you plaace this 301 rule before any other rules you already have.

Comment: entering directly the /vacation-country/ is working like a charm, but when entering the /vacation/country/ it is directing me to a 404. I even created a dummy link (/vacation1/country) to make sure no other lines affect this rule.

Comment: Still not working as expected. It's redirecting me to: http://www.domein.com/home/webrage/public_html/wintersport/vacation-country/ instead of http://www.domein.com/vacation-country/

Comment: Running the second option direct, is no problem. It's the first option, that is still not working as expected.